# Pasar datos de un DataGrid a un textbox en Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un problema con un DataGrid en Asp.Net.
Tengo mi datagrid conectado a base de datos cuando esta ejecutando desearia que al seleccionar una fila o columna en cierta posición del datagrid se pase al textbox y ya e intente de varias maneras pero ninguna me sirve, intente con estas lineas de código con Tostring y .text al final. Muchas gracias quien me logre ayudar.

```
 protected void dgv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNombres.Text = dgv.Rows[1].Cells[1].ToString();

        txtNombres.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.Rows[1].Cells[3].ToString());
        txtNombres.Text = dgv.Rows[1].ToString();

        txtNombres.Text = dgv.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        txtNombres.Text = dgv.SelectedRow.Cells[1].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Tienes algún `bindingSource` de tu código de conexión a tu base de datos? o un `DataSet`

Comment: Si tengo un dataset

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo un `dataset` podrias agregar un `bindingSource` con el `dataTable` con el cual trabajas en tu vista, posteriormente asignas al `DataBindings - Text` el valor que corresponde a cada `TextBox`. Esto hara todo el trabajo por ti.

Pero seria muy largo para explicarlo, asi que te coloco un codigo que podria funcionarte:

```
this.txtNombres.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["nombres"].Value);
```

Tendrías que saber con que nombre te trae la celda, aunque como tu lo aplicas (con indice numeral) creo que también funcionaria.

Podrias aplicarlo en eventos como `CellClick` y `KeyUp`.